# Which is the correct way to setup free shipping and handling in magento?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I am trying to setup shipping and handling in my website, I setup free shipping for the orders with minimum of 99 dollars but I want to set a shipping and handling fee of 9.98 (flat rate FedEx Standard Ground) for orders below 99.

How can I set it up so that when the order is 99 or above the free shipping is automatically selected and when its below 99 the shipping is automatically selected to 9.98 (flat rate FedEx Standard Ground)?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [table rate shipping](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can set up the FedEx method to make FedEx Ground free for orders $99 and above and use whatever the quoted rate is for orders under $99. Just set Free Method to Ground, Free Shipping with Minimum Order Amount to Enabled, and Minimum Order Amount for Free Shipping to 99, and disable all other shipping methods.